# JPA error in kotlin : Class 'Student' should have [public, protected] no-arg constructor

Tags: kotlin, jpa

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem: 'Class 'Student' should have [public, protected] no-arg constructor'?

It's  moaning about the relation to `SchoolLesson`

```
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne


@Entity
data class Student(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = -1,

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_lesson_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    val report: SchoolLesson,

)
```

#EDIT added SchoolLesson on request

```
    import javax.persistence.*
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

    @Entity
    data class SchoolLesson(
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(nullable = false)
      val id: Long = -1,
    
      @NotNull
      val name: String = "",
    )
```

Comment: Could you show `SchoolLesson` class?

Comment: @Ice added it to the question for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use data classes for @Entities. It causes a bunch of problems later on. Follow best practices listed here: https://www.jpa-buddy.com/blog/best-practices-and-common-pitfalls/.

Comment: You did not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to specify a no-args constructor. The simplest way to do this is by setting default values for all your parameters, overloading your constructor:

```
@Entity class Event(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) var id: Long = -1,
    var title: String = "no title",
    var descriptor: String = "no description" ) {

}
```

Comment: This makes more sense as constructors primarily come in when you haven't set default values for your parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [no-arg compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin), which will add "an additional zero-argument constructor". Details are in the link.

Answer (score 2):

I added the JPA plugin and the issue went away

```
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version kotlinVersion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use @Data, instead declare all the necessary annotations to generate what you need. In this case:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SchoolLesson {
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do not create any constructor for `class A` but create objects of `class A` from other place, that time compiler creates a no argument constructor under the hood & executes without error. On the other hand, when you create a constructor having some parameters explicitly but do not create any no arg constructor explicitly with the hope in mind that constructor will create a one for you that time it will give you compile error. So, when you create constructor having some parameters, then you also need to create a no argument constructor explicitly in your class. Ref Links that might help here

- [Why do we need a default no argument constructor in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078389/why-do-we-need-a-default-no-argument-constructor-in-java)
- https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-define-a-parameterized-constructor-for-a-class-without-defining-a-parameter-less-constructor-in-Java

Answer (score -2):

You may provide default value for all data class properties:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Student(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = -1,

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_lesson_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    val report: SchoolLesson = SchoolLesson()
)
```

Comment: Very wrong declaration with data class! To use data classes it is MUST to:

1) Enable the all-open plugin as it was described above, because this is the only way to make data classes open in the compiled bytecode.
2) Override equals(), hashCode(), toString() in the right way